# How to fix bootstrap empty slide in carousel

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am facing problem with bootstrap carousel. When i return to the tab of the site it shows empty slides and slides next. I am working along with wordpress. I think the empty is the wrapper of the slide. but why does the slide go weird when return to the tab.

[image]

Can you guys please help. Below is my wordpress and bootstrap carousel.

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

<?php

    $rows = get_field('slidershow', 25);
    $row_count = count($rows);

?>

  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">

  <?php for($counter = 0; $counter < $row_count; $counter++): ?>

  <?php if($counter == 0): ?>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <?php else: ?>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="<?php echo $counter; ?>"></li>
  <?php endif; endfor; ?>

  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

    <?php 

    $images = get_field('slidershow', 25);

    $counter = 0;

    if( $images ): ?>

    <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>

      <?php if($counter == 0): ?>

        <div class="item active">
          <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3><?php echo $image['alt']; ?></h3>
            <p><?php echo $image['description']; ?></p>
          </div>
        </div>

      <?php else: ?>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3><?php echo $image['alt']; ?></h3>
            <p><?php echo $image['description']; ?></p>
          </div>
        </div>

      <?php endif; $counter++; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

  </div>


  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi guys i notice that even with the default bootstrap carousel code from the w3schools(Bootstrap JS Carousel). The empty div is showing when your click or return to the tab of the site. [link](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_carousel2&stacked=h)